# Por que da error con setsetBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android-studio, android-imageview

## Lo que quiero lograr

Tengo 3 **ImagenView** que utilizo como botones ya que los hago circular ya que no puedo crear botones circulares creo que por la configuración de **Material design**

Al momento de seleccionar uno cambiara de color un poco para figurar la selección

Ya que solo puede estar seleccionado una opción el botón anterior se des seleccionara para seleccionar el nuevo, no se si lo que realizo es la mejor manera de hacerlo pero es lo que se me ocurrió.

### Lo que hago es lo siguiente

Mis **ImageView**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/insidadVerde"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:onClick="seleccionVerde"
                android:background="@drawable/botton_circular_verde"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/insidadNaranga"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/botton_circular_naranja"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:onClick="seleccionNaranaja"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/insidadRojo"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/botton_circular_rojo"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:onClick="seleccionRojo"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Uno de los métodos que tengo para el cambio de color

```
public void seleccionVerde(View view) {
        ImageView colorVerde, colorNaranja, colorRojo;
        colorVerde = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadVerde);
        colorNaranja = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadNaranga);
        colorRojo = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadRojo);
        selectVerde = !selectVerde;
        if (selectVerde) {
            colorVerde.setBackground(seleccionColor(1));
            if (selectNaranja) {
                colorNaranja.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_naranja);
                selectNaranja = !selectNaranja;
            } else if (selectRojo) {
                colorRojo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_rojo);
                selectRojo = !selectRojo;
            }
        } else {
            colorVerde.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_verde);
        }
    }
```

El metodo **seleccionRojo()** es el siguiente

```
public void seleccionRojo(View view) {
    ImageView colorVerde, colorNaranja, colorRojo;
    colorVerde = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadVerde);
    colorNaranja = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadNaranga);
    colorRojo = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadRojo);
    selectRojo = !selectRojo;
    if (selectRojo) {
        colorRojo.setBackground(seleccionColor(3));
        if (selectVerde) {
            colorVerde.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_verde);
            selectVerde = !selectVerde;
        } else if (selectNaranja) {
            colorNaranja.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_naranja);
            selectNaranja = !selectNaranja;
        }
    } else {
        colorRojo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_rojo);
    }

}
```

El metodo **seleccionColor()** contiene lo siguiente

```
private GradientDrawable seleccionColor(int color) {
    GradientDrawable circulo = new GradientDrawable();
    circulo.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    circulo.setSize(50, 50);
    circulo.setCornerRadius(25);
    switch (color) {
        case 1:
            circulo.setColor(Color.argb(60, 14, 253, 46));
            break;
        case 2:
            circulo.setColor(Color.argb(63, 255, 170, 48));
            break;
        case 3:
            circulo.setColor(Color.argb(60, 14, 253, 46));
            break;
    }
    circulo.setStroke(10, Color.argb(63, 244, 67, 54));
    return circulo;
}
```

Al dar clic en el mismo **ImageView** funciona correctamente pero 
al dar clic en el **ImageView** de color rojo o naranja que tienen un método casi similar al mostrado anteriormente, se supone que se debe regresar al color original la selección anterior para dar la sensación de que solo se puede tener seleccionado uno.

pero me marca el siguiente error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yordy.richard.hospital, PID: 7728
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.yordy.richard.hospital.PrincipalActivity.seleccionRojo(PrincipalActivity.java:184)
```

El error lo marca en la siguiente linea

```
colorVerde.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botton_circular_verde);
```

Comment: agrega tu mètodo : seleccionRojo()

Comment: @Elenasys ya agregue el metodo seleccionRojo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que puede estar pasando es que estás intentando setear tus botones buscando un control dentro de la vista que dispara el `onClick()`:

```
 public void seleccionRojo(View view) {
    ImageView colorVerde, colorNaranja, colorRojo;
    colorVerde = view.findViewById(R.id.insidadVerde);
    ...
}
```

En este caso la vista que dispara el `onClick()` es el mismo botón, por lo que la buscar dentro de él `view.findViewById(R.id.insidadVerde);` devolverá un nulo, y por consecuencia `setBackgroundResource()` devolverá error.

Intenta declarar tus botones de manera global y setealos solo una vez dentro del método  `onCreate()`

```
ImageView colorVerde, colorNaranja, colorRojo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tuviewlayout);

    colorVerde = findViewById(R.id.insidadVerde);
    colorNaranja = findViewById(R.id.insidadNaranga);
    colorRojo = findViewById(R.id.insidadRojo);
}
```

Así te ahorrarás declararlos en cada método de `onClick` correspondiente a cada botón.